# Reference to component

Tags: node.js, knockout.js

Using knockout.js in node, how can I get a reference to a child VM component, which was invoked from a template?

### Illustration

I have a Question Model, VM, containining a custom Resource component, with it's respective Model and VM. The Resource VM registers a custom component and receives a Resource Model object as a parameter, which was constructed by the parent Question Model. This constructed resource is passed as a parameter with the template:

QuestionModel.js

```
 this = new QuestionModel(...);
 this.resource = new ResourceModel(some data);
```

question-template.html

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: questions, as: 'question' }">
    <!-- question related -->
    <resource params="resource: question.resource"></resource>
</div>
```

ResourceVM.js

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {

    var ko = require('knockout');

    var ResourceViewModel = function ResourceViewModel(params) {
        this.resource = params.resource;
        this.somethingSpecific = function() {
            return 'some value manipulate from this model';
        }
    }

    ko.components.register('resource', {
        viewModel: {
            createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
                return new ResourceViewModel(params);
             }
         },
         template: {
             require: 'text!/resource-template.html'
         }
    });

    return ResourceViewModel;
});
```

I want to be able to call functions of the Resource VM (like question.resourceVM.somethingSpecific()).

**What is a proper way of getting a reference to a component child?**

The only solution I can think of is to pass the parent object with the parameters and extend it from child, which is obviously bad.

Comment: A good answer would probably depend on what exactly `somethingSpecific()` does. If the parent VM really needs a reference to the child viewmodels, I don't see a way around of having the child register itself at the parent on creation. This might be easier if you create an additional `resource` binding and use it inside the `resource` components' template, since bindings have access to the `bindingContext` and can look up the parent VM.

Comment: `somethingSpecific()` generates an aggregate for a list of contenteditable's child nodes (I'm doing some custom tokenization/ autocomplete with a contenteditable). I only need this one reference to the component, so I hope I can avoid the extra observable.

Comment: You question data model already has a reference to the resource data model. Maybe `somethingSpecific` really belongs there, instead of the resource view model?

Comment: The reason why I want to call `somethingSpecific()` from the parent is efficiency. This function in itself does a rather heavy computation on the VM, so I'd like to call it only when necessary.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but that's what I mean. Your `QuestionModel` already has access to `this.resource`, so having  `somethingSpecific()` as an attribute on `ResourceModel` instead of `ResourceViewModel` would solve the problem nicely. I would argue that manipulating data is the responsibility of the entity that holds it; the job of the `ResourceViewModel` is only to provide glue between the data model and the DOM.

Comment: That's a solution. My concern is that for several reasons the data has to come from the DOM. I have poor experience with the MVVM pattern, but I assumed that an iteration on a list of child nodes, in order to get data from them, should be done from the VM. 
Would it be also bad if I created a reference of the VM in the Model and have it call my function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78095/discussion-between-janfoeh-and-ile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `QuestionModel` already has access to `this.resource`, so the way forward might be by doing it through the data models, instead of through the view models. Having `somethingSpecific()` as an attribute on either `QuestionModel` or `ResourceModel` instead of `ResourceViewModel` would solve the problem nicely.

I would argue that manipulating data is the responsibility of the entity that holds it; the job of the ResourceViewModel is only to provide glue between the data model and the DOM.

```
var QuestionModel = function QuestionModel() {
  this.somethingSpecific = function somethingSpecific() {
    this.resource.doStuff();
  };
};

this = new QuestionModel();
this.resource = new ResourceModel(some data);
```

You could then give your `resource` component access to the `question` instead of the child `resource`:

```
var ResourceViewModel = function ResourceViewModel(params) {
    this.question = params.question;
    this.resource = this.question.resource;
}
```

Comment: I would still keep `somethingSpecific()` within the Resource child (as it deals with dom elements of that view model), but I got the idea - I should rework my implementation so that the model stores and computes all data. Thanks again for the help!